# Heroku not recognising ONE model in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rake task gives an error on the line Ohline.count when run on Heroku.  It works fine on local dev.

**NameError: uninitialized constant Ohline**

Other models can be used, eg Lvpole.count

I have tripple checked the name of the model is correct, twice.

```
task :ohlines => :environment do
  desc "Rake task to fetch and import ohlines data"
  puts "LvOhLine..."
  csv_file = Net::HTTP.get(URI('https://etc/file.csv'))
  puts Lvpole.count
  puts Ohline.count  <= error
  Ohline.import(csv_file)
end
```

I had previously renamed the model and migrated the db (from free to hobby)

What might have gone wrong? Is there a cache to clear? I've tried forcing some redeploys with minor changes.

Comment: What's filename of `Ohline`?

Comment: Ohline.rb.  and I can do things like Ohline.count in console.

Comment: the rake task works locally btw

Comment: @adaam - good point! it shouldn't be capital O.  doh.  silly local osx and its capitalisation blindness trips me again!